# Is it possible to change core javascript function with extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to change default javascript parameters. I want to create extension for prevent getting screen size of web sites. When websites would get clients screen size it will notify and prevent it. Is it possible to do that?

[image]

```
>> window.screen.width
1366
>> window.screen.width = 800
800
>> window.screen.width
1366
```

Comment: You can use `Object.defineProperty`. Like `Object.defineProperty(window, "screen", {get: function(){ }, set: function(val){ }});` Some properties are configurable, some are not. Though it's not reccomended to alter global objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.screen` is a built-in getter/setter. If you want to notify when it's accessed, you can overwrite the property with your own getter:

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'screen', {
  get() {
    console.log('Tried to get window.screen, preventing');
    throw new Error();
  },
  set() {
  }
});

console.log(window.screen.availHeight);
```

You might consider returning dummy data instead, though, so that the page's JS still has a chance of running, eg:

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'screen', {
  get() {
    console.log('Tried to get window.screen, preventing and returning false data');
    return {
      availHeight: 800,
      availLeft: 0,
      availTop: 0,
      availWidth: 800,
      colorDepth: 24,
      height: 800,
      orientation: {angle: 0, type: "landscape-primary", onchange: null},
      pixelDepth: 24,
      width: 800,
    };
  },
  set() {
  }
});

console.log(window.screen.availHeight);
```